# Retag request Xp -> Windows-XP on Super User

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Over on Super User the grass keeps needing a trimming. Requesting a retag  on

- [XP](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xp) × <del>30</del> 0

to

- [Windows-XP](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp) × <del>2027</del> 2,189

Comment: And now I know what Eight Days is up to on SU...

Comment: indeed it does.  duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42283/su-retag-request-hdd-bluescreen-karmic-torrent

Answer (score 2):

They're all done. For now.

Until next time!

Comment: locked question is now retagged.  all done.